# What is an efficient way to combine multiple columns into one column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe from an imported file that looks similar to the following:

```
stim1.1 <- c(23)
stim1.2 <- c(24)
stim1.3 <-c(266)
stim2.1 <- c(276)
stim2.2 <- c(564)
stim2.3 <-c(250)

mydata <- data.frame(stim1.1, stim1.2, stim1.3, stim2.1, stim2.2, stim2.3)
```

There are many more rows, but this is the general idea. The output is as follows:

```
stim1.1 stim1.2 stim1.3 stim2.1 stim2.2 stim2.3
23      24      266     276     564     250
```

I'm trying to get an output similar to the following:

```
stim1    stim2
23       276
24       564
266      250
```

Right now I am doing the following to acheive this:

```
mydata <- pivot_longer(mydata, c("stim1.1", "stim1.2", "stim1.3"), values_to = "stim1")


mydata <- pivot_longer(mydata, c("stim2.1", "stim2.2", "stim2.3"), values_to = "stim2")
```

This works, but it is incredibly inefficient for large sets of data. I imagine that there is a more elegant way to do this, but I'm not sure what that is. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in with in one `pivot_longer()` statement:

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(mydata, cols= everything(), names_sep = "\\.", names_to = c(".value", "NumValue"))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  NumValue stim1 stim2
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 1           23   276
2 2           24   564
3 3          266   250
```

If you like you can now delete the "NumValue" column with `dplyr::select()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split` + `list2DF`

```
list2DF(
  split(
    unlist(mydata),
    sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(mydata))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  stim1 stim2
1    23   276
2    24   564
3   266   250
```

---

Or, you can use `reshape`

```
reshape(
  cbind(
    id = 1:nrow(mydata),
    mydata
  ),
  direction = "long",
  idvar = "id",
  varying = -1
)[-(1:2)]
```

or even shorter (thanks for the suggestion from @thelatemail)

```
reshape(mydata, varying=TRUE, direction="long")[2:3]
```

which gives

```
    stim1 stim2
1.1    23   276
1.2    24   564
1.3   266   250
```

Comment: @thelatemail wow, that's a magic I didn't know. thanks for sharing!